# Hive join query very slow

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, bigdata

I am trying to runt he following query with 6 reducers, but I always see only one reducer getting launched. Not sure why the tasks parameter is ignored.Please help. (I use a older version of hive, hence not in queries are not supported)

set mapred.reduce.tasks=6;

select concat(test1.col_0,test1.col_1) from test1 left outer join test2 where concat(test1.col_0,test1.col_1) = concat(test2.col_0,test2.col_1) and concat(test2.col_0,test2.col_1) IS NULL;

Comment: Can you try converting the first where clause to an ON condition: select concat(test1.col_0,test1.col_1) from test1 left outer join test2 ON concat(test1.col_0,test1.col_1) = concat(test2.col_0,test2.col_1) where concat(test2.col_0,test2.col_1) IS NULL;

Answer (score 0):

Re-posting the comment as an answer:

Can you try converting the first where clause to an ON condition:

```
select concat(test1.col_0,test1.col_1) from test1 left outer join test2 ON concat(test1.col_0,test1.col_1) = concat(test2.col_0,test2.col_1) where concat(test2.col_0,test2.col_1) IS NULL;
```